# How to change Pin position on location changed event in xamarin forms google maps

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app to track users live location.I have the updated positions from geolocator plugin.when i get new positions i change the pin position.But it is not changing in the map.Here is the code,

this method is called in every 1 sec

```
private async void TrackMe()
{
    var current = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
    current.Accuracy = 30;
    float bearing =float .Parse ( current.Heading.ToString ());
    var pins = new Pin { Label = "ME", Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("path4646.png"), Flat = true 
    };
    var latitude = current.Latitude;
    var longitude = current.Longitude;

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        pins.Position = new Position(latitude, longitude);
        pins.Rotation = bearing;
        if (MapTrack.Pins.Count == 0)
        {
            MapTrack.Pins.Add(pins);
        }
        MapTrack.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewPosition(new Position(latitude, longitude)));
    });
}
```

Any help will appreciated, thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Is it because you are always creating a new pin with updated location but only assigning it to `Pins` when existing pin count is 0? The pin, once added, is never updated.

Comment: I only want to add pin to the map for the first time , next time I want to change the position of the pin in order to get a smooth tracking expirience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, can you make this change to the code and see if it works? I don't have the dev environment set up to try it out first myself.

```
private async void TrackMe()
{
    var current = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
    current.Accuracy = 30;
    float bearing =float .Parse ( current.Heading.ToString ());
    var pins = new Pin { Label = "ME", Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("path4646.png"), Flat = true 
    };
    var latitude = current.Latitude;
    var longitude = current.Longitude;

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        pins.Position = new Position(latitude, longitude);
        pins.Rotation = bearing;
        if (MapTrack.Pins.Count == 0)
        {
            MapTrack.Pins.Add(pins);
        }
        else
        {
            MapTrack.Pins[0] = pins;
        }
        MapTrack.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewPosition(new Position(latitude, longitude)));
    });
}
```

I am assuming Pins collection has a writeable indexer. You'll need to modify else part if that is not the case.